# SSIS expressions

Tags: ssis, expression

Need to find the rows with an uneven (1,3,5,7) number of characters in column [name] and send them to one flat file source.

And again the rows with even (2,4,6,8) number of characters in the same column [name] which goes to another flat file source.

But I need to know the expression to do this in a tool (conditional split?)

Answer (score 0):

```
LEN( «character_expression» ) % 2
```

If returned 1 then even number (1, 3, 5, ...), if returned 0 then odd number (2, 4, 6, ...).
Of course the best choice to do this in Conditional Split Transformation...

Sorry... In Condition of Contitional Split Transformation goes these two expressions:

```
LEN( «character_expression» ) % 2 == 0
LEN( «character_expression» ) % 2 == 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot, 
in my conditional split I get an error, saying that the expression is not boolean.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: try adding double quotes around the 1 and 0. like "0" and "1".